# Is my torso short for my legs length?

Tags: flexibility, mobility, anatomy, bones

I can't touch my toes with my finger tips when bending(feel tightness in my hamstrings),and when compared to my friend,the degree of bend was same but for that he could touch his toes,but I couldn't.I am a 5"6' guy of 21 yrs age and am quite active otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed variance between individuals' proportions, but your ability to touch your toes, relative to your friend's ability, is no measure of your torso length relative to your legs' lengths.

Comment: But can't it be an indication of my lack of reach due to my anatomy given that we both are demonstrating a similar amount of flexibility in the  action of trying to touch the toes while sitting!?

Comment: @sagnikdas, I'm sorry: I don't think I can provide further assistance.